# executing a python program with tensorflow library embedded from java + (spring) did not work

Tags: java, python, spring, tensorflow

1. first, I have this java program within spring framework that is trying to call a simple hello world python script.
2. it worked and returned a "hello world"
3. so then I tried to run a python script with tensorflow library embedded, then it returns nothing.(nothing printed in the console)
4. python+tensorflow

   import tensorflow as tf
   import sys
   import os

   os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
   import tensorflow as tf

   image_path = sys.argv[1]
   image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

   label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                      in tf.gfile.GFile("logs/trained_labels.txt")]

   with tf.gfile.FastGFile("logs/trained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
       _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

   with tf.Session() as sess:

   ```
   softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

   predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
            {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

   top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

   for node_id in top_k:
       human_string = label_lines[node_id]
       score = predictions[0][node_id]
       print('%s (Percentage = %.2f )'  %  (human_string, (score * 100 )))
   ```
5. java script

   package com.test;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.*;

   public class HelloWorld extends Thread{

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
   ```

   //      System.out.println("Hello worldss!!!!");
           try {
               Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\Python3.6.3\Python36\python D:\EclipseIDE\TestJava\src\com\test\classify.py  D:\EclipseIDE\TestJava\src\com\test\crack1.jpg");
               p.waitFor();

   ```
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   ```

   //          Thread.sleep(1000);
               String s;
               while((s = in.readLine())!=null) {
                   System.out.println(s);
               }
               if (s == null){
                   System.out.println("lol");
               }
   //          System.out.println(in.readLine());
           }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace(System.err);
           }
       }
   }
6. question - can I run a python with tensorflow embedded from java program?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the saved tensorflow model and run the prediction from java. Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java#supported_platforms)

Load the train_graph.pb file and use the feed and fetch function to send and receive data.
You can follow the [android tutorial](http://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html)